# p5.js background only filling half of background

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So I'm just getting into p5.js, and when I go to use the `background()` function, it only fills in half the background on a sort of diagonal.

[image: This is how the background is drawn.]

I've drawn some shapes just experimenting with them and colors, but I can't figure out why I can't draw a whole background.

This is my code:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(200,200);
}

function draw() {
    background(0,100,50);
    stroke(255,0,0);
    fill(0,255,0);
    rect(50,50,20,20);

    stroke(0,0,255);
    fill(255,0,0);
    ellipse(60,40,20,20);
}
```

The same thing happens if I try using samples of other programs too, so it must not be something with my code.

Comment: Works fine here: https://codepen.io/felipe_mare/pen/xgXGQp What are you using to run your code?

Comment: This code works fine for me. Also note that the image you posted is 400x400 pixels instead of 200x200 pixels, which is suspicious. Do you have some kind of zoom enabled on your computer?

Comment: I am loading this code through an html file, in browser, then just loading the html file in google chrome.

Comment: @Pepe when I view the codepen.io link you shared, it prints incorrectly for me, same as it does in the picture, could it be an error because I'm on Ubuntu?

Comment: So I think I've found an issue, when I view the index.html in my browser, it seems to think it's in a canvas with the size 400x400.

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome zoom was 110%, which for some reason doubled the default canvas size in my index.html, disabling the default zoom corrected the issue. Thank you Kevin and Pepe.